# Using the Collection.model attribute in Backbone.js

Tags: typescript

I have following code:

```
    class Student extends Backbone.Model { 
        // id, lastname, firstname, birthdate 
    }


    class StudentList extends Backbone.Collection { 
        model = Student;  
        ... 
    }
```

I get always an error like this.

```
    Type of overridden member 'model' is not subtype of original member defined by type 'Collection'    ...
```

In an official example is nearly the same code. There it works (Todo->TodoList). The declaration of Collection in my backbone.d.ts is this.

```
...
model:Model;
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the value of the var `model` to the *type* `Student` with `model = Student;`

To override the variable you would need `model:Student;` and to set the value you would need `model:Student = nameOfSomeInstanceOfClassStudent;` (or just `model = nameOfSomeInstanceOfClassStudent;`) or, if you're initializing it with a new student, `model:Student = new Student();`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by assigning the model type in the constructor.

```
 export class Users extends Backbone.Collection<Models.User> {
     constructor(models?: Models.User[], options?: any) {
      super(models, options);

      this.model = Models.User;
     }
    }
```